# Wordpress page showing offline status

Tags: wordpress, offline

my wordpress site is showing offline status.
I've done changing the htaccess, changed theme and also deactivated all of my plugins, but the problem remains. any solutions?

Comment: What error displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the WP_DEBUG mode for more information on what exactly could be the reason behind your problem. This can be performed easily via FTP or file manager like one in cPanel, as well as from SSH. Open the *wp-config.php* file and find the following line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Change this line of code to:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

This will output the error message in your browser when you access your website. If there is still no output of the actual error message, you can try check the "*error_log*" file in the root directory of your WordPress instance.

If you provide us here with the error message, I will be glad to provide more information if possible.